# Matplotlib hist doesn't calculate the correct heights of bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

I read data from a csv file and then calculate the amount of bins according to sturges rule. Then I make a histogram using matplotlib, but I don't get what I expect.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

height = [167, 170, 173, 173, 173, 174, 175, 178, 180, 180, 182, 182, 184, 185, 187, 188, 189, 190, 192, 193, 195, 197, 199, 202]
plot.hist(height, bins=5)
plot.xlabel("Sizes")
plot.ylabel("Count")
plot.show()
```

Which gets me the following output:

[image: Resulting hist plot]

But I would expect the counts in the different ranges to be:

```
167 - 174.0: 6
174.0 - 181.0: 4
181.0 - 188.0: 6
188.0 - 195.0: 5
195.0 - 202.0: 3
```

What can I do to fix the plot or am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: You're counting some of the values twice. The bins are upper bound non-inclusive. 174 isn't in both the [167, 174) range and the [174, 181) range. 174 is _only_ in the [167, 174) range. This makes 5 values in that range [167, 170, 173, 173, 173]. The same is true with the [181, 188) range there are only 5 values [182, 182, 184, 185, 187] since 188 isn't included in the range.

Comment: "174 is only in the [167, 174) range. "
Did you make a mistake here? 174 belongs to 174-181 or am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah. It's that's a mistake. You are correct it's only in the [174, 181) range. The rest of the comment is correct and I even show the values in the [167,174) range in the next sentence not including 174... my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a text version of what you
graphically depicted.

```
>>> hst = plot.hist(height, bins=5)
>>> for patch in hst[2].patches:
...     print(patch.get_bbox())
... 
Bbox(x0=167.0, y0=0.0, x1=174.0, y1=5.0)
Bbox(x0=174.0, y0=0.0, x1=181.0, y1=5.0)
Bbox(x0=181.0, y0=0.0, x1=188.0, y1=5.0)
Bbox(x0=188.0, y0=0.0, x1=195.0, y1=5.0)
Bbox(x0=195.0, y0=0.0, x1=202.0, y1=4.0)
```

Input points (heights) belong to exactly one bin.
Each bin is a half-open interval,
similar to what `range()` uses.
The first couple of bins are:

- 167 <= height < 174
- 174 <= height < 181
- ...

The *final* bin is a minor exception to that rule:

- 195 <= height <= 202

---

Apparently you want some of these input points
to appear in neighboring bins.
Consider defining some small epsilon value:

```
    eps = 1e-3
```

and then add or subtract that from
selected data points to acheive the desired result.

Notice that adjusting the initial (`167`) value
by epsilon will adjust the start of *all* bins,
possibly giving you what you were looking for.
And similarly for the final (`202`) value.

---

Let's assume these are height measurements
in cm for some population of individuals,
and that the measurement technique is precise
to roughly a millimeter.
That might correspond to this
(non-deterministic!) situation:

```
import numpy as np

eps = .1
height = np.array(height) + np.random.normal(scale=eps, size=len(height))
```

(Use `list( ... )` on that if you prefer not to work with a numpy array.)

Each time you plot such values you will obtain
a slightly different graphical depiction.
They will be plausibly consistent with small real-world measurement errors.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me a lot. I was thinking something is wrong but I didn't know that for example 174 belongs to the upper class.